# Swift 2.0 issue showing notification with custom sound file

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to make my app send a notification with a custom sound file, when user receives an message, but there is an error in `var pushData:NSDictionary = NSDictionary(dictionaryLiteral: "New Message "+myName,"alert","KeepNotification.wav","sound")`
Xcode says that: Cannot invoke initializer for type 'NSDictionary' with an argument list of type '(dictionaryLiteral: String, String, String, String)'

And I don't know what that means, so I'll be grateful if some one showed me the correct line of code.

```
if success == true {

                //This to push notification when message is sent successful with sound ********

                var myName = PFUser.currentUser().valueForKey("profileName") as! String

                var pushData:NSDictionary = NSDictionary(dictionaryLiteral: "New Message "+myName,"alert","KeepNotification.wav","sound")

                var uQuery:PFQuery = PFUser.query()
                uQuery.whereKey("username", equalTo: otherName)

                var pushQuery:PFQuery = PFInstallation.query()
                pushQuery.whereKey("user", matchesQuery: uQuery)

                var push:PFPush = PFPush()
                push.setQuery(pushQuery)



                push.setData(pushData as [NSObject : AnyObject])
                push.sendPushInBackgroundWithBlock{

                    (success:Bool! , error:NSError!) -> Void in

                }

                print("Push Sent")
                //-----------------------------------------------------------------
                print("Message Sent" + myName)
                self.messageTextView.text = ""
                self.mLabel.hidden = false
                self.refreshResullts()


            }

        }

    }

}
```

Thanks, if there is anything unclear I'll edit my question.

Comment: Note that writing "if success { ... }" is enough

Comment: Please use a more descriptive issue title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to initialise an `NSDictionary`, then you can use:

```
var pushData = ["alert" : "New Message "+ myName, "sound" : "KeepNotification.wav"]
```

Refer [NSDictionary Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/) for all the initialiser types available for `NSDictionary` and it's usage.

Comment: `NSDictionary`? This is Swift. Just use `var pushData = [ "alert" : "New message " + myName, "sound" : "KeepNotification.wav"]`

Comment: @MidhunMP No, I think he says that using `NSDictionary` is not needed considering the only use `pushData as [NSObject : AnyObject]`.

Comment: The *syntax* is Swift, but it's more idiomatic (and safer, in terms of type safety) to use a Swift `Dictionary`, not `NSDictionary`.

Comment: @NRitH: Agree with that :)

Comment: @Sulthan: Yes, agree with you. Thanks for notifying that part of code.